# write from standard output to different files (Without screen printing)

Tags: bash

How to write $Log_general to Log1 and Log2 on both time, without printing anything to screen?

remark: Log1 and Log2 files need to update separately from $Log_general, I don't want to copy Log1 to Log2!!

I tried the following but only `Log2` got updated

```
 echo $Log_general 1>Log1 1>Log2
```

or

```
./my_script.sh 1>Log1 1>Log2
```

and with the following there was the problem that `$Log_general` output appears on screen while I aim to write only to the files `Log1` and `Log2`:

```
 echo  $Log_general | tee -a Log1 Log2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `tee` command to pipe output first to one file and stdout, and then the stdout to the second file. Something like:

```
echo $Log_general | tee Log1 > Log2
```

**Edit:**

I didn't see your edit Jennifer before I posted, but the usage above doesn't output to the screen for me (I'm running cygwin though, rather than a Linux terminal - hopefully the output is the same)

Comment: not good because I dont want to write log1 in to Log2 (Log2 need to update only by the "echo $Log_general"

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. I thought you wanted to log the output of a command (in this example, `echo $Log_general`) to two files at the same time, which is what my snippet does.

Comment: @Ash see my last remark (Log1 > Log2
 is illegal Log2 need to update only by the echo...)

Comment: @jennifer: Have you tried to run the command I gave?

Comment: YES but its like I copy Log1 to Log2 and I dont like this because Log2 must be update only by the echo

Comment: Okay, let's say I run the command `echo Hello`. Can you tell what you would like the content of Log1 and Log2 to look like after running that command?

Comment: @Ash "Hello" will be in Log1 & Log2 but sometimes in my bash script I only write to Log1 and some times to both (Log1 & Log2) this is the reason that I don't want copy Log1 to Log2

Comment: @jennifer: I don't actually understand your comments here, but based on your use of `tee -a`, I think what you're after is `echo $Log_general | tee -a Log1 >>Log2` (so as to append to each of `Log1` and `Log2`, rather than truncating).

Answer (score 1):

```
./bash.sh | tee -a /path/to/firstfile
```

If you are trying to append the output of a bash script file to a single file, then the above code will work.

```
./bash.sh | tee -a /path/to/firstfile |tee -a /path/to/secondfile
```

The second bit of code should work to write the same output to two different files. 
I'm using Xubuntu and it works for me.